# How can I use the VLOOKUP in Excel accross different pages, while not getting an error if the value doesn't exist

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, vlookup

I'm currently trying to sum the values of 10 different pages in Excel, where an ID is shared. Then returning that value in a different sheet with the sum of all those values.

This is my current formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,May!B2:D2338,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,April!B2:D2352,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,March!B2:D2387,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,February!B2:D2413,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,January!B2:D2457,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,December!B2:D2470,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,November!B2:D2522,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,October!B2:D2570,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,September!B2:D2601,3,FALSE)+
  VLOOKUP(B2,August!B2:D3074,3,FALSE)
```

As you can see, I'm creating the sum of values for 10 different months. My problem is that, whenever the ID doesn't appear in one or more pages, then I receive an error. Can you help me point how to best use it so it counts only within the pages that the ID exists?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `IFERROR()` to suppress errors. What is your excel version. If it **Microsoft 365** then could try `VSTACK()` then `SUM()`.

Comment: Name the ranges - makes the formula clearer.

Comment: Either of the one if using **MS365** should work: `=SUM(VSTACK(May:August!D2:D2601)*(VSTACK(May:August!B2:B2601)=B2))` **Or**, `=SUM(TOCOL(May:August!D2:D2601,1)*(TOCOL(May:August!B2:B2601,1)=B2))` you don't need `IFERROR()` for this since if not found would return `0` See download example **[Workbook_TOCOL()_VSTACK()](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjHMQ7f8u1_ucre62?e=HxODuJ)**